# Working Maven3 configuration for AppEngine + DataNucleus + JPA 2

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jpa-2.0, maven-3, datanucleus

I'm trying to create GAE project via Maven and I'm facing problem with persistence libraries configuration. I try including different dependencies and specifying different scopes, but I always get some errors like:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/datanucleus/ObjectManagerFactoryImpl
```

.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/spi/ProviderUtil
```

.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/datanucleus/ClassLoaderResolver
```

.

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No persistence providers available for "transactions-optional" after trying the following discovered implementations: org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, eventually I've found the solution for my case:

```
    <!-- Persistence Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine.orm</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-appengine</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdo-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
        <version>[3.1.1, 3.1.99]</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>[3.1.1, 3.1.99]</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-jpa-query</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

I hope it will help somebody with same issues.

Comment: You're using JPA 2, so remove "javax.persistence" (JPA 1) from that list (you use geronimo-specs JPA 2 jar below that)

Answer (score 1):

check the GAE dependencies here
https://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/wiki/Compatibility
Its possible you may be using some incompatible versions.